# how to verify the digital signature in a zero knowledge proof

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I know that the zero knowledge proof is able to prove to the verifier that the holder does in fact ***posess the digital signature*** issued from an issuing 3rd party but...

How does the verifier validate that the signature (which is hidden to the verifier) that the holder possesses is valid?